# #1136 El número de columnas no corresponde al número en la línea 1

Tags: mysql, sql

No comprendo a qué se refiere con este error cuando intento realizar la INSERT en la tabla llamada APUESTAS. ¿Tendrá algo que ver el disparador? Es un AfterInsert, así que no creo. Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
INSERT INTO apuestas (idPartido,idUsuario,importeApuesta,minutosApuesta)
VALUES (30,4,10,45)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trigger:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Historial donde se pretenden guardar toda la actividad mediante trigger:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muestra el código de tu `TRIGGER` supongo que será `apuestas_AI`. Puedes sacarlo haciendo esto: `SHOW CREATE TRIGGER apuestas_AI`

Comment: Añadido. Y he probado borrar el trigger y no da error. Osea que hay algo en el trigger que no le gusta.

Comment: Oye las imágenes no ayudan en este caso, bastaría con que pongas el texto del `TRIGGER` y de paso indica la estructura de la tabla `historial` porque el problema es ahí, que las columnas no coinciden.

Comment: Vaya pensaba que era mejor imágenes, en realidad me cuesta menos un copiar pegar del texto. Disculpa ; )

Comment: Cuando se trata de código nada mejor que el texto: se puede copiar y pegar por nosotros para hacer pruebas. Con las imágenes si quiero probar algo ya me dirás como hago para copiar el código si lo que compartes es una imagen ¿? Además  las imágenes se ven con dificultad en dispositivos pequeños. En cuanto al error, observa el `INSERT` del  `TRIGGER`, hay 6 columnas y 7 valores, he ahí el error... ¿lo ves?

Comment: Vaya, sí que era eso. Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en el `TRIGGER` llamado `apuestas_AI`, el `INSERT` que ejecutas tiene 6 columnas y 7 valores.

Por lo que se puede apreciar, te falta incluir la columna `minutos` en el lugar que le corresponde en la sentencia.

El `TRIGGER` debe quedar así:

```
INSERT INTO historial 
    (
       idUsuario, 
       actividad, 
       idApuesta, 
       idPartido,
       importe,
       minutos,
       fechahora
    )
    VALUES 
    (
       NEW.idUsuario, 
       'Nueva actividad', 
       NEW.idApuesta, 
       NEW.idPartido,
       NEW.importeApuesta,
       NEW.minutosApuesta,
       NOW()
    )
```